# Is there an HTTP response code polling frequency limit?

Tags: java, html, http, polling

I am working on a project in Java that pulls data from a webpage. I want the program to pull any new data within milliseconds of the page being updated. My thoughts are to just request response codes constantly, however I do not know if large quantities of response code requests can drag on a site in the same way a DoS attack would. What I want to know is; is this considered a DoS attack or is this what response codes are for? And is there a response code polling frequency limit? If so how do I find out what it is? Lastly, if none of this can be fast enough, are there alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: At least you should only request `HEAD` to see if the page has changed (or alternatively a conditional `GET`). Busy polling of a website that is not yours is still considered abuse.

Answer (score 0):

If you poll faster than a web server can keep up, then it's basically a DoS attack no matter your intentions. If you get to that point, you won't get response codes back, because you've overloaded the server and it can't respond.

It's not polite to send a lot of requests to a server very quickly, even if the server *can* handle it, but I don't know of any standard that says explicitly, "X requests per second, max"

I guess I would ask, why do you need to poll that quickly / why do you need updates that immediately?